# How to overwrite managed solution in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I exported managed solution S1 from my dev CRM. Then imported it on 'clean' TEST CRM machine. Now I made some changes on dev CRM like deleting and adding some fields from Contact entity. After, I made new export of S1 (as managed).

Now I want to update solution on TEST CRM. I choose 'Overwrite customizations'. But after update solution it is merged. Deleted fields are still present in Contact entity and new ones are added.

How to completely override imported managed solution on CRM?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRM Solutions can't be used to delete invidual items

Check out this blog post - it walks through some steps to overcome that limitation: [Deleting things from a deployed CRM 2011 managed solution package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2012/05/29/deleting-things-from-a-deployed-crm-2011-managed-solution-package.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Installing a solution will never delete fields.  Managed or Unmanaged.  Overwriting Customizations will overwrite forms, views, web resources etc.  But the schema will always be an accumulation of before + solution.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but workaround from Jason's answer did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a solution as managed or unmanaged, you export it as unmanaged or managed.   My guess would be that you exported it from dev as unmanaged the first time, therefore when you are importing it, it isn't overwriting your customizations.  You can test this by attempting to remove your fields in your test environment.  If you are able, then those initial changes must have been imported as a managed solution.

Comment: First sentence, you are right - lapsus. I'll update question. First I imported managed solution on test environment. So that is not cause of problem.